# Definitive list of object properties available through column formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, column-formatting, person-or-group

I have been referring to:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

And also reading multiple blog posts around the subject.

I have not yet found a definitive list of object properties available through column formatting.

I looked around the [SharePoint REST API v1 docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom), but there doesn't seem to be any complete reference there (and I'm not sure if what is available via the API is also available through column formatting).

Does a resource like this exist?

I am specifically trying to find what properties are accessible in a `Person` object.

I want to show the `username` in a column, based of an existing `Person` column.

I have had success implementing this basic formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Person.title]"
}
```

And this has also worked for:  `[$Person.email]`, `[$Person.id]`.

But I cannot see how to access `username` and `workemail`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using column formatting on Person or Group type field you can only access below properties as of now (with example values):

```
{
   "id": "122",
   "title": "Kalya Tucker",
   "email": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "sip": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "picture": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/kaylat_contoso_com_MThumb.jpg?t=63576928822",
   "department":"Human Resources",
   "jobTitle":"HR Manager"
}
```

**Official documentation**:

[Column Formatting in SharePoint - Special string values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#special-string-values) - Check **People fields** section

Comment: By any chance, do you know if these are still the *only* values you can grab from a `Person` column?  That `People fields` section does not seem to be on the linked page anymore.

Comment: Yes, people fields still support the same properties in JSON formatting. I have updated the link in above answer, thanks.